# Laravel - If statement condition

Tags: laravel

Good Day Programmers,

Greetings!

To achieve if a is between 1-10 print good. if a is between 10-20 print bad.

I tried

```
if($a >=10 || $a<=20) {
"good"
} else if{
#other code here for multiple conditions
}else{
}
```

But that gives me an error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<=' (T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL)
```

Could someone help me understand how to

1. Use two conditions in one if statement
2. Use between ( a is equal or greater to 10 and a is equal to or less than 20, as said in the example above).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there's problem with the way you access variable 'a' it should be probably $a

Comment: I forgot to mention $ here as i was speaking in general. Ill update the question

Comment: Please provide real code rather than showing an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be using `&&` when checking range constraints:

```
if($a >= 1 && $a <= 10) { 
    echo "good";
} else if($a >= 11 && $a <= 20) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "something";
}
```

Or use a switch statement:

```
switch(true) {
    case $a >=1 && $a <= 10:
         echo "good";
         break;
    case $a >=11 && $a <= 20:
         echo "bad";
         break;
    default:
         echo "neutral";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as following:

```
@if ($a <= 10)
   Good
@elseif ($a <= 20)
   Bad
@else
   #other code here for multiple conditions
@endif
```